# How to manually access the vertices and surface normals of a model in the plant?

Tags: drake

Is there a workflow to extract vertices/surface normals from the plant without using the standard workflow.
What I have tried is using `plant.get_geometry_query_input_port()`, then use member functions of the `query_object` to get the pairs. `query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints()` or `signed_distance_pairs = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints();`
From one of the returned many pairs, then the point can be extracted using `p_BgCb = signed_distance_pair.p_BCb` in the model registered frame.
My question is: how to get the points from any geometry in the scene in the body's registered frame manually? I tried to look for it in the documentation but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drake doesn't currently support those kinds of queries. `SceneGraph` knows about geometry "specifications" but doesn't deal directly with the implementations. It defers the details to the various underlying engines (as each engine has different requirements; for example, the proximity engine doesn't require a mesh to have normals. So, a mesh acceptable for signed distance queries may not have any normals specified at all.)

From here on, I'm going to assume that you're thinking of geometries that are only meshes (as the ideas of "vertices" doesn't apply to primitives), then the only recourse you currently have would be to parse the mesh yourself. You can find the transforms that pose the geometry in its frame from `SceneGraphInspector::GetPoseInFrame()` or in the world from `QueryObject::GetPoseInWorld()`, but ultimately, you would have to consume the mesh definition, extract the information you care about and then measure and express it in whatever frame you need.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

The related question is: what end are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a way to accomplish the same (or equivalent result) via a different mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I am trying some contact modelling, which requires to manually specify some points on the body as my contact points, rather than using what is computed from the query_object module. How are the points in body registered frame obtained in `.ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints()` then? Cheers.

Comment: Drake computes signed distance with a mix of bespoke calculation and FCL. But it essentially comes down to *a lot* of code the examines the two geometry specifications and applies a custom algorithm to computing the two witness points. There really aren't any shortcuts for finding those points.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am just doing what you said with hard coding. Can I ask: what is the difference between "geometry frame" as in the `signed_distance_pair` and a "register frame" as in `pydrake.geometry.SceneGraphInspector.GetPoseInFrame()`? Not sure if I understand it correctly that the registered frame means the pose of the frame in current context?

Comment: The "geometry frame" in `signed_distance_pair` *is* the frame that is referred to in `GetPoseInFrame()`. What's more important is the relationship between the "geometry" frame and the corresponding `MultibodyPlant` frame. There is one-to-one correspondence between a *body* frame and a *geometry frame*. They are coincident and aligned. So, when `SceneGraph` reports the world position of a geometry frame, it should always match that of the corresponding body's frame in the world. `QueryObject` has a live connection to the plant and updates the geometry frames from `MbP`'s reported values.

Comment: Great!! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: FYI This topic has come up again recently. It seems to be a hot topic and there's now a Drake issue to resolve this: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20653.

Comment: That is fantastic to know! I ll keep an eye! Cheers.